# AWS CLI / Lightsail / update-relational-database-parameters | Creating a slave DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-lightsail

Day one of using AWS CLI so quite the newbie.

It seems the only way to configure my.conf to set server-id is via CLI.

The variations on the commands I have tried are:

`aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name=Database-test --parameters=parameterName=server-id,parameterValue=2`

`aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name=Database-test --parameters parameterName=server-id,parameterValue=2`

`aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name=Database-test --parameters=[{"parameterName": "server-id", "parameterValue": 2}]`

If anyone knows where I am going wrong or if you can't do this on Lightsail I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0):

somehow i need to update my database parameters too. i stuck at this problem for 2 hours before i found the answer.
It should be because missing applyMethod parameters, and your JSON should be escaped using backslash. i recommend using list parameter like example below. 
And you should search for ApplyMethod for your database parameter (You can get it from using  `get-relational-database-parameters` API). Read the doc below for more complete explanation.

```
aws lightsail update-relational-database-parameters --relational-database-name YourDatabaseName --parameters "parameterName=time_zone,parameterValue=Asia/Bangkok,applyMethod=immediate"
```

PS: You must make sure you have "privilege" to update your database parameter (you can assign it in I AM Console from AWS page)

For more information, read below.

I stumble upon this doc, and it help me a lot. most likely it can help you too

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-updating-database-parameters#get-database-parameters